# How to sync OneDrive files to Microsoft Surface RT device?

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-surface, windows-rt

Today I got a brand new Microsoft Surface RT. 
With the touch keyboard this really feels like a small notebook, my only problem is:

How do I sync my OneDrive files to the device? There is OneDrive app installed, but it can't sync, I can only access the files one by one.

And the usual desktop sync program can't be installed since the system is not x86 but ARM instead.

So how do I sync OneDrive to this device??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from [Ed Bott](http://www.zdnet.com/hands-on-with-microsofts-surface-rt-can-it-hit-the-sweet-spot-7000006258/)

There’s no SkyDrive synchronization. This one surprised me when I first discovered it. If you want to access files stored in your SkyDrive account, you’ll need to do so via a web browser or the built-in Windows 8 app, using a live Internet connection. The Windows desktop app that syncs files between a local drive and SkyDrive isn’t available for Windows RT. (You can open an Office document from SkyDrive, disconnect from the Internet, and continue editing it offline. The Office Upload Center will upload your changes later, when you reconnect.)

This no longer applies. Windows RT 8.1 OneDrive works identically to Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

As of right now, you cannot sync skydrive files to the Surface. Unless MS puts out a update to the skydrive app or a third party application appears, it will not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

According to this page at bit.com.au, MS is working on it.  In the mean time, there's apparently no visible issue when using Office (if you're intending to access a file opened in the last 14, changeable to upto 30, days) or the Pic app, at least.

http://www.bit.com.au/News/322030,if-youre-buying-a-microsoft-surface-be-aware-of-this.aspx

Comment: My most important files are in html, so I need the images next to the files, which is impossible right now.

Answer (score 2):

At last they released a sync device for the rt. I havent tested it myself:

http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/da-dk/app/sync-for-skydrive/dba55c55-efdd-42f9-b249-69945c6fab5b

Its not created by microsoft.

EDIT: Apparently in Windows 8.1, Microsoft has enabled the option to choose offline skydrive sync even on the Surface RT 8.1 :)

http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/microsoft-explains-skydrive-integration-windows-81